# is it possible to show google map without internet api v3 javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show google map without internet, is there any way to do it ?

this is simple code for integrate and display map in my webapplication

```
<script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDwEvCr3alGTKBFt23yk4WVqduw4534CJs&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: If you are asking for offline use of the API then the answer is no.

Comment: [10.1 - a. No access to APIs or Content except through the Service. You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't offer an offline version of the Maps API as is. Maps JavaScript API requires an Internet connection to download all the geospatial information it needs to properly display the map. This information cannot be stored and/or served offline.

**UPDATE**

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker regarding offline maps

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827808

Everybody who is interested please star the feature request and add comments to explain your use case. Hopefully this can influence the prioritization on Google side.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use. download google map downloader app to download images/tiles of respective places and you hard disk. then down google map api and store in you project folder.after that you will download some javascript files which are not found. these files you can see on browser console. then you will success. i have used.